# Jquery change color of SVG element using jscolor.js is failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, jscolor

I have a web page in which SVG is embedded. I am pulling references of elements of SVG and creating color swatches for every element using jscolor.js library.

I want to adjust color of these elements using swatches I am dynamically creating on click jquery event listener.

The problem is, after couple of changes SVG element is becoming black due to some error which is assigning 'undefined' fill color to this SVG element.

I am not getting why it not working all the time.

The main function to do this job is as follows

```
$("#svg_obj").on("click", ".badge", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    $(".badge").attr('selection', null);
    this.setAttribute('selection', true);
    var svg_left = ((Math.round(this.getAttribute('width')) - Math.round(this.getBoundingClientRect().width)) / 2);
    $(".selector").css("left", Math.round(this.getBoundingClientRect().x - svg_left) + 'px')
    $(".selector").css("top", Math.round(this.getBoundingClientRect().y) + 'px')
    $(".selector").css("width", Math.round(this.getAttribute('width')) + 'px');
    $(".selector").css("height", Math.round(this.getAttribute('height')) + 'px');
    $(".selector").css("visibility", "visible");
    for (let i = 0; i < this.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var svg_g = this.childNodes[i];
        // console.log(this.childNodes[i].nodeName);
        if (svg_g.nodeName == 'g') {
            var polygons = Array.from(svg_g.querySelectorAll("polygon"));
            var polygons = polygons.concat(Array.from(svg_g.querySelectorAll("path")));
            // console.log(polygons);   
            Object.values(polygons).forEach(val => {
                // console.log(val.attributes.fill.value.substring(1));
                console.log(val);
                $("#status_bar").append("<p class='swatches " + val.attributes.fill.value.substring(1) + "' >Color:<input data-jscolor='{position:&quot;right&quot;}' value='" + val.attributes.fill.value + "'></p>").on('change', '.' + val.attributes.fill.value.substring(1), function() {
                    val.attributes.fill.value = $('#status_bar .' + val.attributes.fill.value.substring(1)).find('input').val();
                    console.log($('.' + val.attributes.fill.value.substring(1)).find('input').val());
                });
            });
        } else {
            // console.log("Not a group " +svg_g);
        }
    }
    jscolor.install();
});
```

[jsfiddle for working code](https://jsfiddle.net/ssdesh/qh7p1t94/12/)

Could you please help to fix this issue?
Thanks

Comment: I have observed that somehow color assignment is taking place second time on its own and that time this 'undefined' value is getting assigned to fill color.

Comment: I tried jquery off but not fixing the issue. May be I am using it at wrong place.

Comment: if I check undefined as 
`if ($('#status_bar .'+val.attributes.fill.value.substring(1)).find('input').val() != undefined) {
      val.attributes.fill.value = $('#status_bar .'+val.attributes.fill.value.substring(1)).find('input').val();  ...` then it works correctly. But I don't think it is a colution.
       }

Comment: Or may be my entire approach is totally wrong!